# How to add watermark to pdf using wkhtmltopdf in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `wkHTMLtoPDF.exe` to convert html files to pdf.
Basically I am using `Codaxy.WkHtmlToPdf` wrapper in c# to create pdfs from html.
I need to add a watermark text to all pages of my pdf file.
Does anybody knows how to do it using `wkhtmltopdf`?